# Nginx proxy for multibranch environment

Tags: docker, nginx, proxy

I am using nginx as a simple proxy service for my multiple dockerized containers (including image with nginx layer as well). I am trying to create vhost for each branch and this is causing a lot of trouble here. What i want to achieve is:

An nginx proxy service should proxy to containers on paths:

- [branch_name].a.xyz.com (frontend container)
- some-jenkins.xyz.com (another container)
- some other containers not existing yet

nginx.conf inside proxy container:

```
upstream frontend-branch {                                          
  server frontend:80;                                            
}     

server {                                                            
  listen 80;                                                      
  server_name ~^(?<branch>.*)\.a\.xyz\.com;

  location / {                                                    
    proxy_pass http://frontend-branch; 
  }                                                               
}
```

nginx.conf inside frontend container:

```
server {
  listen 80;

  location / {
    root /www/html/branches/some_default_branch
  }
}

server {
  listen 80;

  location ~^/(?<branch>.*)$ {
    root /www/html/branches/$branch
  }
}
```

docker-compose for proxy:

```
version: "2.0"
services:
  proxy:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    restart: always

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy
```

Inside frontend project it looks pretty much the same, except service name and ofc ports (81:80).

Is there any way to "pass" the branch as a path for frontend container (e.g. some frontend:80/$branch) ?

Is it even possible to create that kind of proxy? I don't want to use the same image based on nginx as a proxy and as a 'frontend keeper' because in the future I will want to use proxy for more than only one container so having configuration for whole site proxy inside frontend project would be weird.

Cheers

Comment: what you mean by branch name ? If i understood it correctly you want to map multiple domains to multiple containers. If so this can be achievable.

Comment: A branch name of the repository (fetched by git command). If there is a need for a map for multiple containers per branch, that's okay. But those container and images would have to be created/updated dynamically each time some e.g. *.sh script is run (manual or by some webhook). But names or even numbers of those branch containers cannot be evaluate or predicted

Comment: Where are you running the applications to proxy pass? is all your conatiners on the same machine. create a configuration only on proxy and proxy pass all request based on the url.

Comment: Yeah. everything runs inside same machine. I can create proxy_pass but only for existed containers, which is only one container with network alias called frontend so "proxy_pass http: / / frontend" would work for each request similar to [branch].a.xyz.com. But there is nothing dynamic there, each [branch] returns same page. I would create separeted container for each existed branch but as long as alias name is based on service name inside docker-compose.yml it won't work.